# can CakePHP automatically create tables from models?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In python::Pylons i'm able to issue a setup-app command and it will look at my Models and issue the appropriate CREATE TABLE or CREATE INDEX ddl for my particular database.

it seems like this would be a feature in CakePHP, but i'm having trouble finding it.

in fact i see this in the manual:
"You can create your database tables as you normally would. When you create your Model classes, they'll automatically map to the tables that you've created."

which leads me to believe it doesn't exist?

Comment: oh i totally misunderstood how this works in cake.. i guess you don't define the schema in your model file at all.

so nevermind this question, thanks for you response though.. makes more sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's other way around - you can create models, controllers and views by having DB schema. It's more logical to have a DB design schema first.

Check [this out](http://book.cakephp.org/view/113/Code-Generation-with-Bake)

Comment: It's logical to start with the schema for new apps, but it's backwards in the case of installing finished products based on Cake, or in the case of Cake plugins, both of which begin their life on a host server with a codebase expecting a specific schema in the DB that isn't there. I guess the "accepted" solution is to provide an .sql file and have the end user prime the DB manually, but that doesn't satisfy me much. I want a brilliantly simple first-run experience for my finished products.

Comment: There is the bake schema shell that apparently helpes you with that a bit.

Comment: bake schema is able to create new database tables. but in case of adding a table to a new database, it can not handle.

Comment: I can only agree with beporter. Cake's way of handling required new tables is extremely frustrating if you just want to plug in a plugin and expect it to work - like it does in most other frameworks. Bake has never worked for me.

Comment: I hate when I need to answer with links, but there is schema script which create or export the database structure in a file: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-management-and-migrations.html. Bake is a great tool and @THeSHEEEP you should put some effort to make it working. You could always run it with /path/to/php /path/to/cake.php

Comment: Thank you, but when I say Bake has never worked for me, I do mean that. I put days of effort into it (in total by now), and to no avail. Manually calling bake just always produced a number of errors here, some of which were resolvable, some of which were not. In the end, I would have preferred a solution not requiring console tools at all - as is the case in other frameworks.

Comment: Bake is really convenient tool. I really don't know what could be the problem in your set up, but when I see an error, it's usually because of wrong permissions in app/tmp dir which could be sorted either by changing permissions to 777 or make proper configuration e.g. use the apache user or make your user to be in the proper group, but apart from that I haven't much problems since Cake 1.3

Comment: The link in this answer returns a 404 now.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the comments in the accepted answer above lead me to creating this answer.  You can technically create new tables on the fly using the YourModel->query() function.  I am currently using this in a Behavior I am writing.  This works in CakePHP 2.x, pretty sure it works in 1.3 as well.

In the setup function for the Behavior I am checking to see if the table already exists. If it doesn't I create it.

```
$dataSource = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('your DB');
if(!in_array($tableName, $dataSource->listSources()){
    $this->createYourTableFunction();
}
```

In the createYourTableFunction you create a temporary model to run the YourModel->query() against. And just provide it your SQL instructions. When creating your temporary model just set the table parameter to false so you don't get a missing table error.

```
$YourModel = new Model(array('table' => false, 'name' => 'YourModel', 'ds' => 'Your DB'));
$YourModel->query('SQL instruction string');
```